# Number of all bijective functions from A to A.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> Find the number of all bijective functions from A to A. Given set A
>   has n elements

First number of one-to-one functions from A to A is n! as first element has choice of n elements, but second element has only n-1 since by definition of one-to-one it can't go to the first element choice.....
Now with onto functions I am stuck how to do .

I notice this question has been answered previously by induction, I just think a counting proof would be more helpful for me to learn. Also I am unable to follow that argument there.
[Correctness of a proof by induction of number of bijective functions between finite sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868815/correctness-of-a-proof-by-induction-of-number-of-bijective-functions-between-fin)

Comment: Because A has the same (finite!) size as itself, injectivity and bijectivity are equivalent.

Comment: If you're comfortable with the fact that the number of 1-1 functions is $n!$, just try proving that a function $f: A \to B$ where A,B are finite sets of the same cardinality will be bijective if and only if it's surjective (onto)  if and only if it's 1-1.

Comment: For finite sets these bijections are called permutations. For infinite sets I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f : A \to A$ for a **finite** set $A$ is injective if and only if surjective if and only if bijective. You should make sure that you can prove this, and you should understand the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) before you do.

Hence, there are $n!$ bijective functions.